# What do you gain using a private docker repository vs just uploading the container via CLI to Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I thought I required a private docker hub image in order to use non-public docker containers.. but now i realized I can just upload the project via CLI directly to AWS Beanstalk...

So I have to ask, what is the differences.. especially in terms of privacy and security between the two methods of running a web-app docker image

Comment: only users who have the permission to pull the private image from docker hub can start a container from it, non-private (public) images can be pulled by anyone and anyone can start a container from it.

Comment: @lvthillo my question is more... what if there is no image in docker hub at all.. and I just upload the project directly via CLI to EBS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main benefit might be `avoiding duplicate build times`. In a registry you build only once, using a Dockerfile it could build more than once (assuming it could use different hosts).

Another benefit could be `related with Configuration Management`. In a registry you will have a unique image for a given name/tag (unless you enable to rewrite tags) identified by a sha256. If you build the image from a Dockerfile, you will no have certainty of the result (*)

(*) Especially if you install unpinned packages [apt, pip, npm, etc], it could result in images with some differences.

I do not see any special security or privacy difference in both alternatives.

Comment: if I have just gotten started with Docker.. perhaps it's not needed then to have the registry.. but if the webapp fails I guess they might rebuild the docker image from scratch... leading to possible diffs ?

Comment: Correct! The need for a registry will arise when you have more knowledge and more complex scenarios.